# use blend or something else in css to show both body background image and footer color

Tags: css, html, image-processing

I have site http://change.is where i used to use image blend like photoshop.

On this site i using different colors for footer, to divide it into four parts 1st & 2nd color having opacity 0.7 and 3rd color having 0.9 and last color having 0.5. As first three colors having opacity near to 1, so body background grid is not visible properly like 4th one. But i don't want to change the opacity for them.

I need to show like

[image]

but in this screenshot, i reduced the opacity to 0.5, so footer colors not looking  exactly what i want but i need to use same color with opacity 0.7 for first & second color and 0.9 for 3rd color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're trying to do is show more of the grid under the blue, pink, yellow but you don't want to change the opacity. You could photoshop the grid with the colors so you can control the amount of grid boxes shown, then set it as background and repeat-x.